# Dplyr : how to get last observation of a vector in a (very) concise manner?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following example

```
return <- c(0.02,0.0,0.01,-0.04)
date <- c(1,2,3,4)
df_day <- data.frame(date,return)

> df_day
  date return
1    1   0.02
2    2   0.00
3    3   0.01
4    4  -0.04
```

I want to compound the returns, and get the compounded returns at time 4.
A lengthy working solution is the following

```
df_agg1 <- df_day %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(cumret = cumprod(1 + return) - 1,
         compound = last(cumret)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)

> df_agg1
  date return cumret  compound
1    1   0.02   0.02 -0.011008
```

I dont get why the code above cannot be shortened in the following manner:

```
df_agg2 <- df_day %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  summarise(compound= last(cumprod(1 + return) - 1))
```

Here, my code is supposed to return one single value. Indeed, I get the last value (hence, at time 4) of the vector of cumulative products (minus one).

Unfortunately I get

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :    Unsupported vector
>   type language

What is the problem here?
Thanks!

Comment: Try with `nth()` instead: `df_day %>% arrange(date) %>% mutate(compound = nth(cumprod(1 + return) - 1, -1L)) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)`

Comment: thanks! this works but what is not clear is why I even need the `row_number` line? Indeed, here I get back one single value so this should be treated as an aggregation function. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the issues [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2090) and [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1980)

Comment: I think you are confused as to aggregation. You are using `nth()` in `mutate()` .. why do you expect it to aggregate anything ?

Comment: makes sense thanks. I should have used `summarise` instead of `mutate`. However, the problems remains the same. Thanks for helping!

Comment: question edited accordingly

Comment: Here is an alternative: `... %>% mutate(compound = cumprod(1 + return) - 1) %>% slice(n())`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré can you please post your working solution as an answer? `> df_agg2 <- df_day %>%
+   arrange(date) %>%
+   summarise(compound = nth((cumprod(1 + return) - 1),-1L))` does the trick

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That's a valid alternative, although it's not clear to me  if OP wants the 4th row or the 1st one.

Comment: I want the last one, given that I cumulate over time

Comment: `df_day %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  summarise(compound = (cumprod(1 + return) - 1)[n()])` works too. Your solution (presumably) doesn't work because of a bug in the fancy `dplyr` backend.

Comment: I picked the ONLY one that has a bug!! haha